# css animation broken in transition

Tags: html, css

sorry for the title, I really don't know how to write an accurate title for this case. I want to add a css loader and take a look at the 7th item here : http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

but why when I use it the item is not identical with the origianl one? take a look here :

http://jsfiddle.net/fFjXX/

```
 <div class="cssLoader">Fetching...</div>
```

I fist thought it was collision of css name in my project but it's not.

Comment: It looks identical, other than the background color, what are you seeing?

Comment: @TrentonMaki: in Chrome, the third circle leaves a weird little residue. But nothing like that in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site’s [`main.css`](https://github.com/lukehaas/css-loaders/blob/step2/css/main.css) contains these styles that isn’t shown in the CSS for the particular loader:

```
.loader {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

When I [added that to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fFjXX/1/), the residue stopped showing.

Comment: What this is doing is initiating hardware accelerated animation, the artifact that is being seen if a result of software rendering.

Comment: Unless you want to support 10 versions back, you don't need -moz- or -o-